# Block Template per region hook suggestion

Tags: drupal, drupal-theming, drupal-8, drupal-blocks

I noticed that the team have removed the block--[region].twig.html template hook for block.
https://www.drupal.org/node/1968360

However, I have a site migrating from D7 and using the template a lot.

I'm a front end developer, so I do not have any experience in writing custom theme hook, is there any theme hook that I can use to make the template for region works?

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to your the THEMENAME.theme file:

```
function THEMENAME_theme_suggestions_block_alter(array &$suggestions, array   $variables) {

  if (!empty($variables['elements']['#id'])) {
    $block = Block::load($variables['elements']['#id']);
    $suggestions[] = 'block__' . $block->getRegion();
    $suggestions[] = 'block__' . $block->getRegion() . '__' . $variables['elements']['#id'];
  } else if (isset($variables['elements']['#configuration']['region'])) {
    $suggestions[] = 'block__page_' . $variables['elements']['#configuration']['region'];
    $suggestions[] = 'block__page_' . $variables['elements']['#configuration']['region'] . '__' . end(explode(':', $variables['elements']['#plugin_id']));
  }
  return $suggestions;
}
```

I found this code, but I supplement a little bit.